# Socket.io and Passport.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, passport.js

I m trying to use Socket.io and Passport.js,and mongoose I used this https://github.com/jfromaniello/passport.socketio  and my code

```
var cookieParser;
    cookieParser = express.cookieParser('supersecret');
var  session = require('express-session')
    ,RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
```

in route.js

```
      sio.set('authorization', passportSocketIo.authorize({
          cookieParser: connect.cookieParser,
          key: 'session_secret',         
        secret: 'supersecret',    
        store: new RedisStore,     
        success: onAuthorizeSuccess,  
        fail: onAuthorizeFail,   
    }));

    function onAuthorizeSuccess(data, accept) {
        console.log('successful connection to socket.io');


        accept(null, true);
    }

    function onAuthorizeFail(data, message, error, accept) {
        if (error)
            throw new Error(message);
        console.log('failed connection to socket.io:', message);

        // We use this callback to log all of our failed connections.
        accept(null, false);
    }

});
```

I m getting this error.

```
     return done(e);
         ^
 TypeError: object is not a function
  at pass (/Users/ANTEGRUP/Desktop/passport-local-  master/node_modules/passport/lib/passport/index.js:287:14)
at Passport.serializeUser (/Users/ANTEGRUP/Desktop/passport-local-master/node_modules/passport/lib/passport/index.js:289:5)
at IncomingMessage.req.login.req.logIn (/Users/ANTEGRUP/node_modules/passport/lib/http/request.js:48:29)
at Context.delegate.success (/Users/ANTEGRUP/Desktop/passport-local-master/node_modules/passport/lib/passport/middleware/authenticate.js:194:13)
at Context.actions.success (/Users/ANTEGRUP/Desktop/passport-local-master/node_modules/passport/lib/passport/context/http/actions.js:21:25)
at verified (/Users/ANTEGRUP/Desktop/passport-local-master/node_modules/passport-local/lib/passport-local/strategy.js:83:10)
at Object.ondone (/Users/ANTEGRUP/Desktop/passport-local-master/node_modules/passport-local-mongoose/lib/passport-local-mongoose.js:89:24)
```

Comment: Post the stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved its about passport version .I installed latest version.